# Can't download Ubuntu because the VM's screen is too zoom in. Help!

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

[image]I am trying to download Ubuntu 16.04.6 on Virtual Box 6.1 and there is nothing else on there. I am currently using Windows 8.1.

I have tried going to devices >> Insert Guest Additions CD and nothing happen. I have guest additions downloaded on my laptop from a link.

I also tried to resize it but it doesn't let me.

I am in the middle of trying to download Ubuntu but the VM's screen is so zoomed in that I can't choose the options to continue.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the window by right clicking on the header, hold down the right click and move the window.

You can also press tab to get focus on the continue button and then press enter.